# Jquery limit input length to n emails

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a form where an input field is taking emails. I want to limit the emails inputted by the user to 2 or some other value.

Everything is working except that after the last email domain extension, my code is limiting the last characters of the domain extension.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fd1xdohg/

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<input id="emails"></input>
<label id="lbl"></label>
```

JS:

```
$("#emails").keypress(function () {
    pEmails_tmp = extractEmails($('#emails').val());
    if (pEmails_tmp.length >= 2) {
        $("#emails").attr('maxlength', $('#emails').val().length);
    }
});

function extractEmails(text) {
    return text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
}
```

Try giving 2 emails,separated by space (or whatever you want) and you will see that it wont let you write the domain extension after the "." dot.

Any ideas how to limit the input field to n emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've written the first character of the domain TLD, it qualifies the regex, and doesn't let you type any more.

The way i worked around this was to require a blank space at the end of the second, and then don't let any more through.

```
return text.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)\s/gi);
//                                                                   ^^ there
```